# OData-related performance issue

Tags: .net, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having issues with really long response times in a Web API/OData scenario.
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API which in turn calls an ASP.NET Core OData API. Excerpt form logs:

> Issuing Odata request at: 01.34.58.088596
>   Odata controller get at: 01.34.59.414334 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 4519.7697ms
>   OData response received at 01.49.12.56983
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 15042.4031ms

Some obeservations:

- It takes ~1.5 seconds for the OData request to reach the OData controller.
- The OData request takes 4.5 seconds. In the request an EF query is performed, which takes about 0.5 seconds when run on its own.
  Where is the remaining ~4 seconds spent?
- OData response is received after ~15s. Take away the 4.5 seconds for the OData request, where is the remaining 10.5 seconds spent?

Everything is latest version and running in IIS express.

Any input appreciated.